# A command line calculator that supports numbers with commas

Tags: command-line, macos, calculator

I often want to copy/paste some numbers from a website into a calculator to do some quick arithmetic. These numbers are typically formatted for display, so they include commas as thousands separators (1,234,567 instead of 1234567).

I'd like a command line calculator that lets me do basic arithmetic and ignores the commas.

Tools considered:

- `bc`: Does not support commas
- `python`: Does support thousand separators, but they have to be `1_234_567` instead of `1,234,567`.
- Google: supports commas! But I'd prefer a command line tool to a search engine.

I'm on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

#### Conversion, then pipe to bc

You could **remove** any commas **before** handing input to *bc* via command-line.

For example use *sed*, then `|` (speak "pipe")  to *bc*

Just strip off the unwanted comma characters by a regex substitution:

```
$ echo '123,456.78 * 100' | sed 's/,//g' | bc
```

outputs

> 12345678

As executable script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Input bc expression (thousand-separator commas will be removed):'
read line
normalized=`echo -n "$line" | sed "s/,//g"`
echo "Following will be passed to bc: $normalized"
echo "$normalized" | bc
```

Comment: This can be optimised, see answers (also stuffed with other CLI calculators): https://askubuntu.com/questions/378661/any-command-line-calculator-for-ubuntu

Comment: Sure this works, but `bc` is an _interactive_ calculator. Using it this way forces you to use it as a batch process, which isn't quite what I'm hoping for.